# Mysql Query Taking 300 Times More Time Using Simple Wrapper

Tags: mysql, subquery

Query 1: This is the original query

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE twitter_id, ANY_VALUE(city), ANY_VALUE(screen_name) 
FROM twitter_discovery_search_results 
GROUP BY twitter_id

0.0051 seconds
```

Query 2: The same query as above just wrapped as a sub-query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE d.* FROM 
(
    select  twitter_id, ANY_VALUE(city), ANY_VALUE(screen_name) 
    FROM twitter_discovery_search_results
    GROUP BY twitter_id
) as d

1.8321 Seconds
```

I am not able to understand why the second query is taking >350 times more time than the original query?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for doing the second query?

Comment: Not really, was experimenting with different techniques to optimise a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is likely to create a temporary table to store the results of the derived table and then select all values from the derived table. If the derived table is sufficiently large, then MySQL will write its content to the disk slowing the query significantly down.